# About camera settings in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, camera

I'm running an app created with xamarin forms on an Android device.
Even if the location information is turned on with the Android standard camera app, it will be turned off when the camera is called with the created app. Where to check

↓ Set location information to ON with the Android standard camera app
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjO7X.jpg)

↓ When you start the camera with the created app, the location information is turned off.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmNMN.jpg)

■AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION" />
```

■AssemblyInfo.cs

```
[assembly: UsesPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.Internet)]
[assembly: UsesPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage)]
[assembly: UsesPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.AccessCoarseLocation)]   
[assembly: UsesPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.AccessFineLocation)]    
[assembly: UsesFeature("android.hardware.location", Required = false)]    
[assembly: UsesFeature("android.hardware.location.gps", Required = false)]    
[assembly: UsesFeature("android.hardware.location.network", Required = false)]    
[assembly: UsesFeature("android.hardware.camera", Required = false)]    
[assembly: UsesFeature("android.hardware.camera.autofocus", Required = false)]    
[assembly: UsesPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.Vibrate)]    
[assembly: UsesPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.AccessNetworkState)]    
[assembly: UsesPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.AccessMediaLocation)]    
[assembly: UsesPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage)]
```

■camera

```
private async void OnImageClicked()
{

    try
    {

        await Plugin.Media.CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

        if (!Plugin.Media.CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !Plugin.Media.CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
        {
            return;
        }

        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        string result = dt.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
        result += ".jpg";

        Plugin.Media.Abstractions.MediaFile file = await Plugin.Media.CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
        {
            Name = result
        });

        if (file == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        Queue<byte> bytes = new Queue<byte>();
        using (Stream s = file.GetStream())
        {
            long length = s.Length;
            int b;
            while ((b = s.ReadByte()) != -1)
            {
                bytes.Enqueue((byte)b);
            }
        }

        File.Copy(file.Path, "XXXXXXXXXXXX/Pic");

        file.Dispose();

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: does your app have location permissions?

Comment: with newer versions of Android you have to prompt the user for permissions, not just declare them

Comment: I added the current code above

Comment: check the document about request location permissions.https://developer.android.com/training/location/permissions